# How can I load jscript from ajax loaded html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have an html file (index.html) with an empty div that loads its content from another html file (second.html) using ajax.

I'm using [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)  to load a popup containing an audio player for a button click on the index.html.

When I have all the coding on the index.html like below, it works fine and displays the audio player on popup window on button click. - [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3x4W8/)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function audioplay() {
    $( "#audio" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 100,
        width: 335,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 300
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 300
      }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#audio" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="stuff">
     <div id="audio" title="Places Are Connected">
         <audio controls autoplay>
           <source src="media/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
           Your browser does not support this audio format.
         </audio>
     </div>
<button id="opener">Open Popup</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I load the content in "stuff" from the second.html file, it doesn't work properly. Ex:

**index.html**

```
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
 <div id="stuff">
   <!--content from second.html loads here-->
 </div>
</body>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","second.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**second.html**

```
<div id="stuff">
 <div id="audio" title="Places Are Connected">
     <audio controls>
       <source src="http://www.hipstrumentals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Katy-Perry-Ft.-Juicy-J-Dark-Horse-Instrumental-Prod.-By-Dr.-Luke-Max-Martin-Cirkut.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support this audio format.
     </audio>
 </div>
<button id="opener">Open Popup</button>
</div>
```

**.JS file**

```
$(function() {
$( "#audio" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 100,
    width: 335,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 300
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 300
  }
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#audio" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

When I use it like in the above example, the audio player just shows up on the index page itself. And the button appears below the player and does nothing.

I have tried so many methods to try and load JS with ajax but nothing worked so far. And since I'm new to both JS and ajax, I suspect there might be an easy fix that I'm missing. So any help to get it working properly would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it fixed. Was a simple fix as I expected. Just had to make a runPopupJs() function and call it at onload.

```
function runPopupJs() {
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 script.src = 'js/popup.js';
 head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Called it by -

```
<body onload="loadXMLDoc();runPopupJs()">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear what you mean with respect to loading JavaScript via AJAX, since the code you are trying to load doesn't contain any JS. However, as to why the audio player is not showing up as you expect it to, it looks as if the first part of your problem is that you don't have a div (or other element) with ID 'nonen' in index.html. You also don't need to repeat the definition of the 'stuff' div in second.html.

So I would remove the first and last lines of second.html, and change your `onreadystatechange` function to include

```
document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Alternatively, since you're using jQuery already, I'd recommend using the [built-in AJAX routines](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Furthermore, depending on your desired effect I suspect you should be calling the jQuery UI dialog routine *after* you've added the second div (or after every time you load it, if it's changed again later).

For example, your current script could be replaced with something like the following (untested) code. First, you want to make sure that `audioPlay()` can be called at a later time, after your AJAX calls have finished, and also that it doesn't execute immediately on page load, before even the first one has completed.

```
audioPlay = function () { // Define a function to be called multiple times later
  $('#audio').dialog({
    ... // Fill in your options
  });
  $('#opener').click(function () {
    $('#audio').dialog('open');
  });
};
```

Next, you want the `loadXMLDoc()` function to call `audioPlay()` once the loaded HTML has been inserted into the DOM.

```
loadXMLDoc = function () {
  $('#audio').dialog('destroy'); // Get rid of any existing dialog
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'html', // Load some HTML data via AJAX
    url: 'second.html', // From this file (relative URL)
    success: function (data) { // When the HTML has finished being downloaded...
      $('#stuff').innerHTML(data); // ...add it to the div with ID "stuff"
      audioPlay(); // ...and create a dialog for the new div
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michael. However, the 'nonen' was a typo, and I already fixed it. The issue I'm having is not that the audio player is not showing up. It's that it shows up on the index.html page itself. 

I want the index page to only display the button - _<button id="opener">Open Popup</button>_. And the audio player should popup hen someone clicks it. 

The reason why I mention loading JavaScript via AJAX is because I'm loading the JS file separately (as seen in the updated question above.)

Comment: Hi @Michael, even though I got it to work with the below fix, it only works on the first page. You can check the website here - [link](http://flipbook.hesh.me/). Please take a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @HeshanGalahitiyawa. I took a look at the page. I'm not certain what behaviour on it you want, which portion you don't like, and what you'd like it to do instead. However, based on your comments here I think I have a better idea of how you can at least get on the right track. I've updated my answer -- let me know if it helps. If not, please elaborate in your question on what *exactly* is going "wrong" -- what happens that shouldn't, or doesn't happen that should (or both).